# What does a broken arrow mean?

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-3

When hovering over an enemy in combat it changes your cursor to an arrow if you're making a ranged attack. Sometimes the arrow is broken, and other times it's unbroken.

What's the difference between a broken and an unbroken arrow? What causes an arrow be broken?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two types of penalties that can take place when performing a ranged attack.

1. [Ranged penalty](https://heroes.thelazy.net/index.php/Range_penalty) occurs when you are trying to attack a stack of units more than 10 hexes away.
2. [Obstacle penalty](https://heroes.thelazy.net/index.php/Obstacle_penalty) occurs when you are trying to shoot through an object such as a wall.

These penalties are cumulative, so you may be doing only 1/4th of your actual damage.

These penalties can be mitigated three ways:

- [Sharpshooters](https://heroes.thelazy.net/index.php/Sharpshooter) naturally do not incur a ranged nor obstacle penalty
- [The Golden Bow](https://heroes.thelazy.net/index.php/Golden_Bow) on the hero will eliminates all range/obstacle penalties
- [The Bow of the Sharpshooter](https://heroes.thelazy.net/index.php/Bow_of_the_Sharpshooter) does the same and allows ranged units to use their ranged attack on adjacent targets.

Comment: Does firing over obstacles (rocks, walls, et cetera) activate the broken arrow as well?

Comment: @Wipqozn yes, let me update my answer

Comment: @z', Are these modifiers taken before the attack/defense skill modifiers? Or do they apply after everything else has been calculated?

Comment: Also, about the Bow of the Sharpshooter, it's worth to mention that even though in-game descriptions don't say it, the combination artifacts' bonuses are **in addiction** to regular bonuses. So, Bow of the Sharpshooter will still boost your Archery by +30%, Cornucopia is actually giving you +5 to Crystals/Mercury/Sulfur/Gems, etc. :-)

Comment: @Pacerier I think that it's simply multiplicative with damage, i.e. Base Damage is multiplied by the sum of 1 + damage bonuses, then multiplied by 1-X, there X is damage reduction, multiplied for each dmg reducing thing. Then you round down, but can't have less than 1. So, it's simply half of damage you would do/receive in full range, eventually with 1 dmg of difference